# Autofiltering two columns as an OR function

Tags: vba, filtering

I am trying to filter two columns in excel to show all the results that deliver today(two separate columns). I have tried multiple ways, however I keep getting results that reflect an "AND" statement. I feel like I am close with.

```
Sub Playing_Today_v2()
Dim s As String
s = "=" & CStr(Date)


With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("table1").Range
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=s
End With

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("table1").Range
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=s
End With


End Sub
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: do you want the = in the string?

Comment: @qharr actually i was wrong i think...

Comment: [Here's info on multi criteria multi column filtering](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b#bkmk_3).  Get your filter working *manually* and then record a macro of yourself setting the filter, then look at the generated code to see how it's done

Comment: @QHarr also it looks like the `=` is indeed required

Comment: I become learned :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello in order to do this via VBA you will first need to understand how to accomplish it manually 2 ways that come to mind are:

- Add a helper column to the table
- Use an advanced filter

For the helper column add a formula similar to `=OR(Col7=TODAY(),Col9=TODAY())` and filter to that column equals `true`.

For the advanced filter create a 2 x 3 range and populate as follows:

```
Col7 NAME, Col9 NAME
=Today() ,
         , =Today()
```

As use that as your criteria range to do a `OR` selection (if you want an `AND` selection put them on the same line).

Once you have got this working manually it is fairly easy to move to VBA either by adding a new column and adding 1 autofiler similar to your existing code or by using the `Range.AdvancedFilter` method.

If you get stuck with the code please post a question showing how far you get and someone will be able to help.